# Importing Data In Sqoop 1.99.6

Tags: sqoop

I've been able to import data from Oracle in Sqoop 1.99.6 by creating links and jobs. However, I was wondering if the following syntax can be used to import data:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
--username sqoop \
--password sqoop \
--table cities
```

I could only find sqoop.sh file and not sqoop file in `/<sqoop_home>/bin` directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below syntax can be used to import data from Oracle Database to HDFS using Sqoop

/usr/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@:1521:xe  --username  -P--table . --columns "" --target-dir   -m 1

Comment: Thx but as I said only sqoop.sh file exists for Sqoop 1.99.6 version. Sqoop file is present for 1.4 version. Hence the syntax suggested by will throw an error saying  No such file or directory